# How to add menu items runtime in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android

I am using Navigation Drawer Activity Template from Android Studio. I want to add menu items at runtime from my java class in Navigation drawer. Is it possible ? If yes can you please guide me.

I want to show list of courses coming from web service on left navigation drawer. I want user to tap on any course which will open another activity showing details about selected course.

List of courses and their details are in JSON. I can parse json accordingly. All i want to know that how can i create menu items dynamically.

Thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add menu items to your navigation drawer at runtime.

Remove the below from your NavigationView layout ( which inflates your NavigationView menu )

```
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
```

In your activity, you can get navigation instance by using

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You can get menu instance of your navigation view using

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
```

For adding menu items you can use either of the methods provided in 'Menu' instance

```
public abstract MenuItem add (CharSequence title)  or 
public abstract MenuItem add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes)
```

eg:
you can add menuitems/submenu's using the above 'menu' instance like this

```
menu.add("Title1")
menu.add("Title2")
menu.addsubMenu("Title3").
menu.add("Title4")
...
```

Inorder to perform an action when the user clicks on a particular menu item, 
you will be implementing

```
onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

based on the

```
item.getItemId() or item.getText() provided they are unique
```

you can implement your logic

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed help. It works for me.